# How to get a list of the companies and organizations that contributed to a repository on GitHub?

Tags: api, github, github-api

I need to retrieve the name of all the organizations from the contributors of a GitHub repository. I know that the following API request gives the list of the first 100 contributors of a repository, ordered by their number of contributions:

`https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors?per_page=200&anon=true`

However, this API call only shows the metadata from the first 100 contributors of a repo, and there is no information about which organizations they belong to.

What I need is iterating through the list of **all** contributors and retrieve **all** the organizations they belong to. Is there any way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub users may belong to several [organizations](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/about-organizations). The organizations administrator can accept or reject a GitHub user in the organization. On the other hand, Github users can also choose to declare that they belong to a particular company, and this information is displayed on their GitHub profile. Here is an illustrative example:

[image: Example of GitHub user with company and organization]

This information can be obtained via the GitHub API using bash commands (notably `curl`, `jq`, and `grep`). Here are working script examples of how to get this data for the GitHub repository `ConsenSys/teku`.

### Get the list of contributing organizations

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the GitHub API url of each user that contributed to the ConsenSys/teku project.
# Store in a txt file the list of URLs for post processing.
curl --fail --silent --show-error https://api.github.com/repos/ConsenSys/teku/contributors\?per_page\=100\&page\=1\&anon\=true | jq -r '.[].organizations_url' | grep 'https' > teku_contributors_organizations_url.txt

# Iterate over the list of URLs and append the curl result to a txt file.
for i in $(cat teku_contributors_organizations_url.txt); do
    content="$(curl -s "$i")"
    echo "$content" >> teku_contributors_organizations_url_data.txt
done

# Show the organizations that contributed to the project ordered by number of instances
cat teku_contributors_organizations_url_data.txt | grep "login" | sort  | uniq -c | sort -nr > teku_contributors_organizations.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   4   "login": "ConsenSys",
   3   "login": "hyperledger",
   3   "login": "arithm3tica",
   3   "login": "PegaSysEng",
   3   "login": "EntEthAlliance",
   2   "login": "apache",
   1   "login": "tmio",
   1   "login": "splunkdlt",
   1   "login": "solsuite",
   1   "login": "sigp",
   1   "login": "puniverse",
   1   "login": "prrkl",
   1   "login": "openethereum",
   1   "login": "mana-ethereum",
   1   "login": "jbosgi",
   1   "login": "goerli",
   1   "login": "exthereum",
   1   "login": "ethsearch",
   1   "login": "ethjs",
   1   "login": "ethereum",
   1   "login": "eth-clients",
   1   "login": "eclipse",
   1   "login": "deltap2p",
   1   "login": "dappnode",
   1   "login": "byz-f",
   1   "login": "arquillian",
   1   "login": "argentlabs",
   1   "login": "Thera169",
   1   "login": "InternetOfPeers",
   1   "login": "Department-of-Decentralization",
   1   "login": "ChainSafe",
   1   "login": "Centareum"
```

### Get the list of contributing companies

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Get the GitHub API url of each user that contributed to the hyperledger/teku project.
# Store in a txt file the list of URLs for post processing.
curl --fail --silent --show-error https://api.github.com/repos/ConsenSys/teku/contributors\?per_page\=100\&page\=1\&anon\=true | jq -r '.[].url' | grep 'https' > teku_contributors_urls.txt

# Iterate over the list of URLs and append the curl result to a txt file.
for i in $(cat teku_contributors_urls.txt); do
    content="$(curl -s "$i")"
    echo "$content" >> teku_contributors_data.txt
done

# Show the list companies that contributed to the project ordered by number of instances
cat teku_contributors_data.txt | grep "company" | sort  | uniq -c | sort -nr > teku_contributors_companies.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
   5   "company": "Consensys",
   3   "company": "ConsenSys",
   2   "company": "AlmavivA",
   2   "company": "@tmio  ",
   2   "company": "@sushiswap ",
   2   "company": "@eucrypt",
   2   "company": "@element-fi",
   2   "company": "@derivadex",
   2   "company": "@blk-io",
   2   "company": "@PegaSysEng | @ConsenSys",
   2   "company": "@Consensys",
   2   "company": "@ConsenSys @hyperledger ",
   2   "company": "@ConsenSys ",
   2   "company": "@ChainSafe ",
   2   "company": "@ArgentLabs",
   1   "company": "RedHat Inc.",
   1   "company": "Hedera @hashgraph",
   1   "company": "Ethereum",
   1   "company": "Contract Worker for the Ethereum Foundation",
   1   "company": "Base2 Cloud",
   1   "company": "Baisysoft",
   1   "company": "@coinbase",
   1   "company": "@KiFoundation "
```

**NOTE:** For repositories with more than 100 contributors, you may get the message: “API rate limit exceeded.” This issue can be solved authenticating your GitHub account by adding the flag `-u <user>:<token>` to `curl`.